# Document.ExportAsFixedFormat or Document.SaveAs in reverse order

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

it is posible to save Word file as PDF without printer in reverse order?

in normal order it works

```
WD.ExportAsFixedFormat PdfFile, wdExportFormatPDF, , wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, wdExportFromTo, 1, WD.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

but in reverse it wont work

```
WD.ExportAsFixedFormat PdfFile, wdExportFormatPDF, , wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, wdExportFromTo, WD.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument),1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the pages in the document using the  the .Printout method and specifying the first and last page as the last and first page.  This works because you are printing to a pdf.

```
ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF"
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="10 -1", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=False, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
        PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

Comment: I know this, but this requered to be printer installed in system